# Java regex replace with capturing length

Tags: java, regex

```
String pw="pw:(abc)";//Maybe "pw:(12)","pw:(ab123)"...
pw=pw.replaceFirst("\\(.+\\)", "*");

//pw == result:pw:*
```

I want the results: `pw:*****`. `(abc)` must be `*` x 5

Asterisk in quantities equal to the length of the content is matched

Can I use `String.replaceFirst` or `String.replaceAll` only way to implementing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
final String pw = "pw:(abc)";

final String anon = pw.replaceAll("[^pw:]", "*");

System.out.println(pw);
System.out.println(anon);
```

which will result in:

```
pw:(abc)
pw:*****
```

Edit: does not work if the password has p/w/: in it... will try to fix..

Edit #2: This turned out to be harder than I thought, had to go with another approach:

```
    final String input = "pw:(abc) something!";

    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\(.*\\)").matcher(input);

    if (matcher.find()) {
        final String onlyPw = matcher.group();
        final String stars = StringUtils.repeat("*", onlyPw.length());

        System.out.println(input.replace(onlyPw, stars));
    }
```

So, first find the String consisting of "({something})". Then create a String consisting of the number of stars in this string. Then replace the string with the stars in the input.

Note: This does not work if the password or the text after the ) contains parantheses, but then again I doubt you will find a regex that does..

Comment: Looks awesome!But if `String pw = "pw:(abc)bla..bla.."`,I just want to replace the contents of the brackets

Answer (score 2):

```
    String var = "lalala(pw:)()pw:(abc12)lalala()(pw:(a12)pw:() lala";

    for(;;){
        String oldVar= var;
        var = var.replaceAll("(pw\\:\\()([*]{0,})([a-zA-Z0-9]{1})(.{1,})", "$1$2*$4");
        if(oldVar.equals(var)){
            break;
        }
    }
    var = var.replaceAll("(pw\\:)\\(([*]{1,})\\)","$1*$2*");
    System.out.println(var);


RESULT: lalala(pw:)()pw:*******lalala()(pw:*****pw:() lala
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String resultString = null;
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile( "pw:\\((.*?)\\)", Pattern.CANON_EQ );
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher( subjectString );
    if (regexMatcher.find()) {
        resultString = regexMatcher.group();
        return resultString.length();
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```